# combine first name and last name and return object

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary-comprehension

I was trying to combine first name last name in an object and return same object again

I have tried multiple ways with map and foreach but doesn't seem to work

[
{
"id": 1321,
"createdAt": "2022-08-03T12:36:20.096Z",
"UpdatedAt": "2022-08-03T12:36:20.096Z",
"firstName": "g",
"lastName": "prashanth",
"zipCode": "39493",
"NPI": "990343"
},
{
"id": 1322,
"createdAt": "2022-08-03T12:36:20.096Z",
"UpdatedAt": "2022-08-03T12:36:20.096Z",
"firstName": "prasilla",
"lastName": "shaik",
"zipCode": "39493",
"NPI": "990343"
}
]

what i have tried:

```
let final_array: any=[]
data.forEach(function (value: any, a:any) {
let obj: any={}
    console.log(a)
     final_array.push( obj[keys_array[a]] = data[a]["firstName"]+" " +data[a]["lastName"], obj[keys_array[a]] =data[a]["zipCode"], obj[keys_array[a]]=data[a]["NPI"])
})

});
```

required format:

[
{
"name": "g prashanth",
"zipCode": "39493",
"NPI": "990343"
},
{
"Name": "prasilla shaik",
"zipCode": "39493",
"NPI": "990343"
}
]

Comment: What _specifically_ have you tried, because neither map nor forEach made it into your question.

Comment: You have a map in a loop so you change every entry to the ith value over and over again; that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const newArrayOfObj = array.map((obj) => {
 let temp = { ...obj, name: `${obj.firstName} ${obj.lastName}` };
 let res = {};

 for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(temp)) {
  if (key === "firstName" || key === "lastName") continue;
  else res[key] = value;
 }

 return res;
});
```

Comment: while this works but when i push the res object to an array it just combines all objects into one big array like this : [1321, "2022-08-03T12:36:20.096Z", "2022-08-03T12:36:20.096Z", "39494", "990346", "g prashanth", 1322, "2022-08-03T12:36:20.096Z", "2022-08-03T12:36:20.096Z", "39493", "990343", "prasilla shaik"]

Comment: the requires format is mentioned in question. could pls you suggest what to do respectively?

Comment: newArrayOfObj  is as your result

Answer (score 0):

```
    var data = [ { "id": 1321, "createdAt": "2022-08-03T12:36:20.096Z", "UpdatedAt": "2022-08-03T12:36:20.096Z", "firstName": "g", "lastName": "prashanth", "zipCode": "39493", "NPI": "990343" }, { "id": 1322, "createdAt": "2022-08-03T12:36:20.096Z", "UpdatedAt": "2022-08-03T12:36:20.096Z", "firstName": "prasilla", "lastName": "shaik", "zipCode": "39493", "NPI": "990343" } ]

    // console.log( final_array)


let data_1= data.map((object,i) => {
  return {...object, fullName: data[i]["firstName"]+' '+data[i]["lastName"]} ;

});
```

You need to pass index value i to map, and probably also include the fullname construction inside the map. Also the outer loop is not required

Answer (score 0):

if you want full result with added property full name you try @Anuja script.

this script will work as the ouput you mentioned.

```js
const dataAsJson = `[ { "id": 1321, "createdAt": "2022-08-03T12:36:20.096Z", "UpdatedAt": "2022-08-03T12:36:20.096Z", "firstName": "g", "lastName": "prashanth", "zipCode": "39493", "NPI": "990343" }, { "id": 1322, "createdAt": "2022-08-03T12:36:20.096Z", "UpdatedAt": "2022-08-03T12:36:20.096Z", "firstName": "prasilla", "lastName": "shaik", "zipCode": "39493", "NPI": "990343" } ]`;

const data = JSON.parse(dataAsJson);

const changedData = data.map(item => ({ name: `${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}`  
, zipCode: item.zipCode 
, NPI: item.NPI }));
console.log(changedData);
```